# how fast can c++ loop constantly check variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, raspberry-pi, busy-waiting, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm using a busy loop to check when a condition is true and take a picture, but I need to have less than 10millisecond delay when the condition is true, and when my loop detects it.  Is this loop viable?

This is running on a slow raspberry pi zero.

```
for (;;) {

  for (pin = 0; pin < 8; ++pin) {
    // Some other thread changed counter, gets detected here
    if (globalCounter[pin] != myCounter[pin]) {
      //Take picture
    }
  }
}
```

full code I'm looking to adopt:
https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi/blob/master/examples/isr.c

Comment: This should run in way less than 10 ms. But the only way you will know how fast it runs is profiling it/checking yourself. The answer will vary on architecture, code and various other factors.

Comment: 10ms is max, <1ms would be ideal for me

Comment: BTW, You should also be careful when accessing a variable in different threads. Make sure you access them in a thread-safe manner (if you haven't done so already ) And mind cross-thread visibility issues.

Comment: Use a `std::condition_variable` and tell the thread when it's been updated instead of busy-looping.

Comment: Generally unless you need sub-microsecond latency, you shouldn't be using busy-wait.

Comment: I hope `globalCounter` is `std::atomic<int> globalCounter[]` or something like that, otherwise this has undefined behaviour if another thread writes it.  (Compilers will potentially hoist the loads out of the loop if `atomic` doesn't stop them)

Comment: @super: the `condition_variable` has no guarantees about latency, although working most of the time, it could sometimes wait longer.

Answer (score 4):

Code latency, specially those that depend on hardware, should be tested in conjunction with the rest of the code and in the target environment.

I believe it is impossible to give a "yes/no" answer without actually running a test in the physical system, with everything implemented.

My only suggestion would be that busy loops are usually a waste of resources and hard to maintain and can often be avoided by triggering the desired behavior only when a hardware flag is set or when the target variable changes in code.

Comment: The code I'm looking at is from a popular library and it's using busy loop so not by my choice see link.

Comment: You could adapt it. Albuquerque is right; busy waiting is bad and you have no good reason to do it. Especially when resource constrained!!

Comment: Usually, API examples are not the best regarding efficiency and coding style. They are usually made to exemplify a functionality of the library and to simplify everything else. I believe the cost of making a busy wait is being "ignored" in the example for the purpose of not adding too much complexity to it.

Comment: @bakalolo: 10ms is a *very* long time.  You can easily use OS-assisted sleep/wake stuff like a condition variable or just SIGSTOP / SIGCONT.  If you're worried, make sure your kernel is using 1000HZ scheduling interval, not 100, so worst-case scheduling latency is something like 1ms plus a few microseconds to actually wake up a process.